# Continuous Random Variables - Calculating Probability

Tags: probability

In a pollutant measurement process five(5) air samples are collected. Each has, independently of the others, pollutant content following a uniform distribution with a minimum value 0 gr/m3 and maximum 12 gr/m3. The result is negative if all 5 samples have pollutant contents of less than 3.5 gr/m3. What is the probability that the result will be positive?

Can anyone give me a hand here? Do I have to use the Fubini theorem? Is it correct to think P(X>3.5)?

Comment: "The result is negative if all 5 samples have pollutant contents of less than 3.5 gr/m3." How does this lead you to think that the final answer is P(X>3.5)? And for which X?

Comment: Well, I tried dressing up the numbers. I concluded that there are five samples with random contents. So, maybe 5x ,with x ε [0,12]. And then what is the probability for x to be higher than 3.5.

Comment: Again: "The result is negative if all 5 samples have pollutant contents of less than 3.5 gr/m3." Hence the number of contents less than 3.5 gr/m3 is irrelevant except to know that it is 5 or different of 5, right?

Answer (score 0):

If each sample $X_i$ is distributed $X_i \sim U[0, 12]$ and all $X_i$'s are independent of each other then you just multiply the probability of each individual sample being below $3.5$:
$$
\mathbb P \left(\bigcap_i \lbrace X_i \leq 3.5 \rbrace \right) = \prod_i \mathbb P(\lbrace X_i \leq 3.5 \rbrace) = \left( \frac{3.5}{12} \right)^5
$$